# Add Entries Python-LDAP

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-ldap

I'm trying to add entries with python ldap. I'm getting a naming convention error. My code is

```
import ldap 
import ldap.modlist as modlist

LOGIN = "" 
PASSWORD = '' 
LDAP_URL = "ldap://127.0.0.1:389" 
user='grant'
l = ldap.initialize(LDAP_URL) 
l.bind(LOGIN, PASSWORD) 
dn="ou=Enki Users,dc=enki,dc=local" 

attrs = {}
attrs['objectclass'] = ['top','organizationalRole','simpleSecurityObject']
attrs['cn'] = 'test'
attrs['userPassword'] = 'test'
attrs['description'] = 'User object for replication using slurpd'

# Convert our dict to nice syntax for the add-function using modlist-module
ldif = modlist.addModlist(attrs)

# Do the actual synchronous add-operation to the ldapserver
l.add_s(dn,ldif)

# Its nice to the server to disconnect and free resources when done
l.unbind_s()
```

The error is:

```
ldap.NAMING_VIOLATION: {'info': "00002099: NameErr: DSID-0305109C, problem 2005 (NAMING_VIOLATION), data 0, best match of:\n\t'dc=enki,dc=local'\n", 'desc': 'Naming violation'}
```

The code that runs but doesn't insert the user into the correc organizational unit is the following code. However even though it runs I can't find the user in active directory. Please help me find whats wrong. I'm basically making a django webform for user management.

```
import ldap 
import ldap.modlist as modlist

LOGIN = "" 
PASSWORD = '' 
LDAP_URL = "ldap://127.0.0.1:389" 
user='grant'
l = ldap.initialize(LDAP_URL) 
l.bind(LOGIN, PASSWORD) 

dn="cn=test,ou=Enki Users,dc=enki,dc=local" 

attrs = {}
attrs['objectclass'] = ['top','organizationalRole','simpleSecurityObject']
attrs['cn'] = 'test'
attrs['userPassword'] = 'test'
attrs['description'] = 'User object for replication using slurpd'

# Convert our dict to nice syntax for the add-function using modlist-module
ldif = modlist.addModlist(attrs)

# Do the actual synchronous add-operation to the ldapserver
l.add_s(dn,ldif)

# Its nice to the server to disconnect and free resources when done
l.unbind_s()
```

Answer (score 0):

I speculate (but have not tested to prove it) that the root cause of your error is that your entry does not contain a "naming attribute" that matches the leftmost attribute in the DN of your entry, which in your case is ou=Enki Users.  To add this naming attribute to the entry, you can add the following line in the part of your code that populates the attrs dict.

attrs['ou'] = 'Enki Users'